# Error en Modelos y Vistas Django

Tags: python, bootstrap, django, vistas, modelos

Tengo un proyecto en Django, en este proyecto tengo dos modelos principales: Transacciones y cuenta. Dentro del modelo Transacciones manejo dos formularios, uno de ingresos y otro de gastos, donde el usuario como su nombre lo dice inserta sus ingresos economicos y en el otro sus gastos, categorizandolos y filtrandolos por fecha. Cuando un usuario se registra en la aplicación automáticamente se le asigna una cuenta en el modelo Cuenta con su id y fk de usuario. Tengo el siguiente error, te lo voy a explicar con un ejemplo.

Supongamos que hago un ingreso de 1.000.000 y un gasto de 500.000 en la tabla Transacciones. La tabla Cuenta queda con 500.000. Ahora cuando actualizo el ingreso y cambio 1.000.000 por 500.000 en vez de mostrarme Cuenta en 0 porque eso da el (ingreso - gasto), me muestra 1.000.000, lo toma como un ingreso más, no actualiza el saldo de Cuenta. También pasa viceversa con los Gastos.

> Modelo Cuentas

```
class Cuentas (models.Model):
saldo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=False, null=False)
fk_user = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, limit_choices_to={'is_superuser': False})

def actualizar_saldo(self, monto):
    self.saldo += monto
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.fk_user)
```

> Modelo Transacciones

```
class Transacciones (models.Model):
fecha = models.DateField ()
monto = models.DecimalField (max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=False, null=False)
es_ingreso = models.BooleanField(default=True)
fk_categoria = models.ForeignKey(CategoriaGasto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
fk_fuente = models.ForeignKey(FuenteIngreso, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
fk_cuenta = models.ForeignKey(Cuentas, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Transacciones, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    cuenta = self.fk_cuenta
    if self.es_ingreso:
        cuenta.actualizar_saldo(self.monto)
    else:
        cuenta.actualizar_saldo(-self.monto)
```

> Vista Editar Ingreso

```
def editar_ingreso(request, id):
transacciones = Transacciones.objects.get(id=id)
if(request.method == 'GET'):
    formatted_fecha = transacciones.fecha.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  # Formatear la fecha
    form = IngresosForm(instance = transacciones, initial={'fecha': formatted_fecha})
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'id': id,
        'fecha_actual': transacciones.fecha, 
    }
    return render(request, 'test1/editar_ingresos.html', context)

if(request.method == 'POST'):
    form = IngresosForm(request.POST, instance = transacciones)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'id': id,
        'fecha_actual': transacciones.fecha,
    }
    return redirect('/ver_ingreso/')
```

> Vista Editar Gasto

```
def editar_gasto(request, id):
transacciones = Transacciones.objects.get(id=id)
if(request.method == 'GET'):
    formatted_fecha = transacciones.fecha.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  # Formatear la fecha
    form = GastosForm(instance = transacciones, initial={'fecha': formatted_fecha})
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'id': id,
        'fecha_actual': transacciones.fecha,
    }
    return render(request, 'test1/editar_gastos.html', context)

if(request.method == 'POST'):
    form = GastosForm(request.POST, instance = transacciones)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'id': id,
        'fecha_actual': transacciones.fecha,
    }
    return redirect('/ver_gasto/')
```